# ion-toggle button tappable over mask

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-popup, ion-toggle

Ionic Version: 1.x

Platform: all

ion-toggle button is clickable even after a popup is on

http://codepen.io/ankitaurfrnd/pen/JKJprp

```
<ion-toggle>Sample toggle Button</ion-toggle>
$ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
     template: 'It might taste good'
   });
```

Toggle button should not be clicked when mask is on.
Is there a workaround to fix this behaviour ?

Comment: what is your question

Comment: I have edited the question @MohanGopi , please help

Comment: use  **ng-disabled**  to make the toggle button disabled after it is clicked @Ankita Os

Comment: added ng-disabled="true" in <ion-toggle> , I think it does not work with ion-toggle @MohanGopi

Comment: **<ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in settingsList"
                    ng-model="item.checked" 
                    ng-checked="item.checked" 
                    ng-disabled="emailNotification===true">
          {{ item.text }}
        </ion-toggle>**  check the above one like this